# cx_freeze looking for submodule in local directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am compiling my python script with Cx_freeze, and it's looking for subprocess in my machines local directy:

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUPzr.png)

Heres the code I am using to compile:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import subprocess

exe=Executable(
     script='makeCSV.py',
     base='Win32Gui',
     )
includefiles=[]
includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=['subprocess']
setup(

     version = '0.0',
     description = 'No Description',
     author = 'Name',
     name = 'MakeCSV',
     options = {'build_exe': 
{'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
     executables = [exe]
     )
```